# Adobe commerce Cloud Enable Application lock for indexer

Tags: magento2-cloud, adobe-commerce

I am trying to enable `use_application_lock` for indexer from .magento.env.yaml file. When i add and verify by using php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools cloud:config:validate it throws error

Can someone help me to enable the setting via .magento.env.yaml file.

Followed reference from https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/#using-application-lock-mode-for-reindex-processes

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to add the use_application_lock value for Magento Cloud? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried right now to add the config but the validation passed flawlessly

Please make sure your Magento/AC version is compatible with the configuration (on the documentation they require a 2.4.3 or bigger) and that you only have a single "indexer" node.
Of course make sure you don't have any other errors in the env.php.